# Does Confluent Parallel Consumer maintain ordering across topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

All topics have the same number of partitions and all messages use compatible message keys.  I need to consume messages from multiple topics and merge the data according to certain criteria, and I don't want to deal with the concurrency issues that arise if two threads simultaneously consume messages that need to be merged together.

Here's an example that's equivalent to my use case.  Suppose I have a bunch of veterinary clinics, each of which has a vetId.  Each clinic has human clients (one to many), and each human client has pets (cats and/or dogs, one-to-many).  Every time a clinic creates or updates a record for a human, cat, or dog, a message is produced (separate topics for humans, cats, and dogs), with the vetId as the message key.  A pet has a humanId pointing to its owner.  My application needs to store a composite record for each human, with certain data about them and all of their pets.  I currently have a consumer per topic, and when two consumers simultaneously process messages (e.g. a dog and a cat) for the same humanId, they knock heads at the persistence layer and one needs to try again.  I'd like to avoid that by having all messages for a given vetId, from any of the three topics, processed by the same thread.

I'm currently using separate Confluent Parallel Consumers, with ordering by key, one for each topic.  If I change to a single consumer for all three topics, will the order be maintained across the topics, solving my problem?  Are there other solutions available?

Comment: This will never be solvable in consumer Level, even if it did guarantee ordering, which it doesn't. If the parallel processing takes longer for one record than the other, it may change the order. Use thread safe transactional updates.